# Aggregate realtime data in KStreams

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I want to sum one columns data based on the key specified. Stream is like id(String) Key, value(Long).

```
val aggtimelogs: KTable[String, java.lang.Long] = stream
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(
               () => 0L,
              (key: String, value: java.lang.Long, aggregate: java.lang.Long) => value + aggregate)
```

//Failing here

Getting

```
Unspecified value parameters: : Materialized[K, VR, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]
```

How to do in Scala?

Kafka version is

```
compile "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.0.0"
compile (group: "org.apache.kafka", name: "kafka-streams", version: "2.0.0"){
    exclude group:"com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
}
```

Even I tried this

```
val reducer = new Reducer[java.lang.Long]() {
      def apply(value1: java.lang.Long, value2: java.lang.Long): java.lang.Long = value1 + value2
    }

    val agg = stream
          .groupByKey()
          .reduce(reducer)
```

Also this

```
val reducer : Reducer[Long] = (value1: Long, value2: Long) => value1 + value2
```

Says

```
StreamAggregation.scala:39: type mismatch;
 found   : (Long, Long) => Long
 required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Reducer[Long]
    val reducer : Reducer[Long] = (value1: Long, value2: Long) => value1 + value2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it like this

```
val aggVal = streams.groupByKey().reduce(new Reducer[Double]() {
    def apply(val1: Double, val2: Double): Double = val1 + val2
  })
```